# Change CSS based on is_user_logged_in

Tags: php, css, users, login

How do I activate certain CSS lines depending on if a user is logged in or not?

**Here's how it looks:**
[image: login mask]

I'm currently building a login mask for a client of ours and here's essentially what I want to do:

if_user_is_logged_in -> container-height: 30px; else container-height: 160px;

**Here's what I got:**
[image: the code because it's easier to read this way]

In case anyone is unable to tell, I had help with the first bits of code as well.

**So to sum up again:**

> if user is logged in -> style:"height:30px;"   default is 160px.

I really appreciate the help I got from this community so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `logged-in` class added by [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) to target your CSS rules.

```
.container { height: 160px }
body.logged-in .container { height: 30px }
```

Comment: So essentially.. I don't even need PHP, I can just add that into the CSS-File of my theme?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I knew of the "logged-in" class but apparently I had a brainfart or something. I appreciate the help!